# Looping requests and appending or merging to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this script that pulls data from Kaikos API and puts it in a pandas dataframe then writes to a CSV file. Sometimes the request data returns a continuation token this is then attached to the URL and the rest of the data is available.

I need to make my code run this process in a loop until there are no more continuation codes. And I need to either merge or append each dataframe then write them as one CSV at the end. I have no clue on how to do this. The last if statement gets the token and add it the URL but now how do I repeat the process with the new URL? How do I stop when they are gone? How do I combine all this data?

I'm going through the append and merge docs but it's not really helping.

```
    import requests
    import json
    import pandas as pd
    import time
    
    interval = '1h'
    page_size = '1000'
    url = f'https://us.market-api.kaiko.io/v2/data/trades.v1/exchanges/cbse/spot/btc-usd/aggregations/count_ohlcv_vwap?interval={interval}&page_size={page_size}'
    KEY = 'xxx'
    headers = {
       "X-Api-Key": KEY,
       "Accept": "application/json",
       "Accept-Encoding": "gzip"
    }
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    j_data = res.json()
    parse_data = j_data['data']
    c_token = j_data.get('continuation_token')
    today = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    
    if c_token:   
       url = f'https://us.market-api.kaiko.io/v2/data/trades.v1/exchanges/cbse/spot/btc-usd/aggregations/count_ohlcv_vwap?interval={interval}&page_size={page_size}&continuation_token={c_token}'
    
    # create dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(parse_data), orient='columns')
    df.insert(1, 'time', pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp.astype(int),unit='ms'))    
    
    print(url)
    df.to_csv(f'kaiko-data-{today}.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Data with continuation token:

```
{'query': {'page_size': 1, 'exchange': 'cbse', 'instrument_class': 'spot', 'instrument': 'btc-usd', 'interval': '1h', 'sort': 'desc', 'ch': True, 'aggregation': 'count_ohlcv_vwap', 'data_version': 'v1', 'commodity': 'trades', 'request_time': '2021-01-21T17:43:21.829Z'}, 'time': '2021-01-21T17:43:21.933Z', 'timestamp': 1611251001933, 'data': [{'timestamp': 1611248400000, 'open': '31017.12', 'high': '31949.99', 'low': '30980.01', 'close': '31910.7', 'volume': '1687.7296551800025', 'price': '31453.507769478947', 'count': 18657}], 'result': 'success', 'continuation_token': 'eHS2F4YczupYKnGrosahFiBi1SVXrFdADpDZf6jtiWDTcLQSgrLzRnJWgTZrbok1VMfZa8Z1ntSiEqbFDPfQN8jNiMNgsjHmRZYazR6yk8GoyQ4N6pyYXdhnLVzZqwLSPya9Lqvb3ZSZH9kWZ4jmyZrwtAZzugDd', 'next_url': 'http://us.market-api.kaiko.io/v2/data/trades.v1/exchanges/cbse/spot/btc-usd/aggregations/count_ohlcv_vwap?continuation_token=eHS2F4YczupYKnGrosahFiBi1SVXrFdADpDZf6jtiWDTcLQSgrLzRnJWgTZrbok1VMfZa8Z1ntSiEqbFDPfQN8jNiMNgsjHmRZYazR6yk8GoyQ4N6pyYXdhnLVzZqwLSPya9Lqvb3ZSZH9kWZ4jmyZrwtAZzugDd', 'access': {'access_range': {'start_timestamp': 1610928000000, 'end_timestamp': 1612223999000}, 'data_range': {'start_timestamp': 1608249600000, 'end_timestamp': 1612223999000}}}
```

Comment: can u provide one sample output of the API response? without a continuation token as well as with a continuation token.

Comment: `while(c_token):`... then move all the necessary code into the while loop. As far as making all the dfs into one just put them all into a list and then `pd.concat` the list at the end. You are closer than you probably realize.

Comment: added the data with continuation token but the data without it is too big to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution

```py
    import requests
    import json
    import pandas as pd
    import time
    import os
    
    interval = '1h'
    page_size = '1000'
    url = f'https://us.market-api.kaiko.io/v2/data/trades.v1/exchanges/cbse/spot/btc-usd/aggregations/count_ohlcv_vwap?interval={interval}&page_size={page_size}'
    KEY = 'xxx'
    headers = {
       "X-Api-Key": KEY,
       "Accept": "application/json",
       "Accept-Encoding": "gzip"
    }
    my_csv_file = "my_csv_file.csv"
    c_token = True
    
    while(c_token):
        res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        j_data = res.json()
        parse_data = j_data['data']
        c_token = j_data.get('continuation_token')
        today = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

        if c_token:   
            url = f'https://us.market-api.kaiko.io/v2/data/trades.v1/exchanges/cbse/spot/btc-usd/aggregations/count_ohlcv_vwap?interval={interval}&page_size={page_size}&continuation_token={c_token}'

        # create dataframe
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(parse_data), orient='columns')
        df.insert(1, 'time', pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp.astype(int),unit='ms'))    

        print(url)
        if(my_csv_file in os.listdir()): #that means file already exists need to append
            csv_string = df.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-8', header=False)
            with open(my_csv_file, 'a') as f:
                f.write(csv_string)
        else: #that means writing file for the first time
            csv_string = df.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-8')
            with open(my_csv_file, 'w') as f:
                f.write(csv_string)
```